# Read values from a binary file in C

Tags: c, file, binaryfiles

this is my problem: I don't know how to read the integers from a binary file. I need a solution for understand the problem behind the code.

This is the image of my binary file:
[image]

This is a format to memorize 32 bit integers in little endian. For example we have a file with 3 values: 1, 2 and 3, with this format they willl be codified in:
01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 or 01 FF FF FF ... .

I wrote some line of code and I do not understand why it does not work. The debug don't give me errors.

This is my code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int *leggiinteri2(const char *filename, size_t *size)  
{
FILE *f;
int *p = NULL;
f = fopen(filename, "rb");
if (f == NULL) {
    p = NULL;
}
else {
    size_t nInteri = fread(size, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    if (nInteri != 1) {
        if (feof(f)) {
            p = NULL;
        }
        if (ferror(f)) {
            p = NULL;
        }
    }
    else {
        p = malloc(sizeof(int)*((int)size));
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        nInteri = fread(p, sizeof(int), *size, f);
        if (nInteri != *size) {
            if (feof(f)) {
                p = NULL;
            }
            if (ferror(f)) {
                p = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
}
fclose(f);
return p;
}
```

Comment: `(int)size` I think you don't want to cast a `size_t` pointer to `int` and use it as size.

Comment: fscanf(<file*>,"%d",<destination addr>)

Comment: @Osiris it's the only way I've found to give the "right" size to my pointer p. I don't know others

Comment: **advice:** when you manipulate binary files, enforce your [integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) using for instance `int32_t` (defined in ` <stdint.h>`)

Comment: `size` is a pointer, so it holds an address. You take the address and cast it to `int` (may overflow). Then you use the address as size. You probably wanted `malloc(sizeof(int) * *size)`.

Comment: @DDS Since he is trying to read binary files, I don't think this will work.

Comment: @Osiris I understood

Comment: @PicaudVincent I'll keep it in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution, it took a lot of time but it was worth it, now I understand the logic behind it.

This is the code for those who need it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int *leggiinteri2(const char *filename, size_t *size) 
{
    FILE *f;
    int *p = NULL;
    f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (f == NULL) {
        p = NULL;
    }
    else {
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END); //It tells me how many values ​​there are in 
                              //the file, both those that I need and those 
                              //that do not 
        long dim = ftell(f); // I assign to dim the value that tells me 
                            //ftell, conditioned by the previous function
        dim = dim / 4; //because I want the integer values (int = 4 bytes)
        *size = dim;
        p = malloc(sizeof(int) * dim);
        fseek(f, 0, 0);
        size_t n = fread(p, sizeof(int), *size, f);
        if (n != *size) {
            if (feof(f)) {
                p = NULL;
            }
            if (ferror(f)) {
                p = NULL;
            }
        }
        if (n == 0) //serves to check for empty or NULL files
            p = NULL;
    }
    fclose(f);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: To remain portable replace `dim = dim / 4;` by `dim = dim / sizeof (int);` or by the shorter equivalent: `dim /= sizeof (int);`

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like:

```
    fread (buffer, sizeof(char), 8, fid);
    x = (s32)(((buffer[0]<<24) & 0xFF000000) + ((buffer[1]<<16) & 0x00FF0000)
            + ((buffer[2]<< 8) & 0x0000FF00) + ( buffer[3]      & 0x000000FF));
```

I am not sure of the order (little or big endian). If KO, reverse the buffer indice 3, 2, 1, 0.

Comment: what is the meaning of the variable `x`?

Comment: For those who are not used to endianness issues, is KO referring to the reversed OK, essentially meaning _not OK_?